# How to combine several mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two mat files named databaseA.mat and datalabelB.mat which have different sizes, databaseA.mat is 8100 x 80 double and datalabelB.mat is 1 x 80 double. I need to combine them into one mat file but don't change their size. Actually I have combined them with the following code

```
ALoad = load( 'databaseA.mat' );
BLoad = load( 'datalabelB.mat' );
save( 'databaseAB.mat', 'ALoad' );
save( 'databaseAB.mat', 'BLoad', '-append' );
```

but result "struct" type data, whereas I don't desire it.

I have asked in other forum too, they suggested to use this following

```
ALoad = load( 'databaseA.mat' );
BLoad = load( 'datalabelB.mat' );
a = ALoad.a;
b = BLoad.b;
save( 'databaseAB.mat', 'a', 'b' );
```

but it gives me an error

```
Reference to non-existent field 'a'.
Error in combineAB (line 8)
a = ALoad.a;
```

Could you correct it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe I missing something, can you not just do:

```
ALoad = load( 'databaseA.mat' );
BLoad = load( 'datalabelB.mat' );
save( 'databaseAB.mat', 'ALoad', 'BLoad');
```

or if you want to combine them:

```
ALoad = load( 'databaseA.mat' );
BLoad = load( 'datalabelB.mat' );
ABLoad = [ALoad;BLoad];
save( 'databaseAB.mat', 'ABLoad');
```